How do we mask a Trail Renderer
So i have a trail renderer in Unity i want to mask it when it passes a image i have added Mask to the Image UI components. Later i figured out it is kind of a waste as trail renderer is a 3D Object and Mask only works with 2D UI component's.
So now how do i mask the trail renderer to only render when not in the mask area. i noticed trail renderer has a Mask Options but for some reason it never works.
I also tried with shaders but even then the trail render was not maskable.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/109810/masking-with-3d-object-in-unity

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

So the closest i got to the answer was to give custom shader to the quad which will act as a mask and a custom shader to the trail renderer this works but i am still trying to figure out. how to mask it using a 2D image.
heres the shader for the Image (mask) :
Shader "Custom/MaskShaderStencil"
{
    SubShader
    {
        // Draw into the stencil buffer
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        Pass
        {
            Stencil
            {
                Ref 1           // Reference value
                Comp Always     // Always write into the stencil buffer
                Pass Replace    // Replace buffer contents with Ref value
            }

            // No need to render any color output, only update the stencil buffer
            ColorMask 0
        }
    }
}

and here it is for the trail renderer :
Shader "Custom/TrailRendererShaderStencil"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
        Pass
        {
            // Use the stencil buffer to check if the pixel should be rendered
            Stencil
            {
                Ref 1           // Reference value
                Comp NotEqual   // Only render where the stencil value is not 1
            }

            // Trail rendering
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
            ZWrite Off
            Cull Off

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            v2f vert (appdata_t v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                return tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}

So not the optimal solution but still a solution.
If you guys find a way to mask it with a image let me know.
Thank you.
